# How to shade the whole Google Map except for radii?

Tags: java, android, maps, android-studio, fog-of-war

I am implementing line-of-sight into a strategy game I am developing, and I would like to shade the map darker outside of the LoS of the player and their structures (fog of war). The trick is, this is a location-based strategy game for android using the Google Maps API.

Now, I know how I would draw just one circle for the LoS: by drawing a dark circle centered on the antipode of the play or structure in question. The only problem is I could only do this for one structure at a time, as the shade would essentially overlap and override any other LoS circles. This is a position that I can ultimately settle with if there is no other option.

What I would rather do is essentially shade the map except for the radii around the player and any of their structures. See the images below for an example of what I am talking about. The red dots are the structures, the white circles are the Line-of-Sight, and the black area is of course the shaded remainder of the map:

[image: Fog of war illustration]

Comment: You may want to review past Q&A with the [tag:fog-of-war] tag, as this is a fairly common confusion for new developers who aren't yet familiarized with depth/stencil buffers or drawing to off-screen render targets as temporary intermediates before compositing the final image.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Looking over these questions, I don't see any which pertain to location based games on the google maps api, which I believe is what I specifically need.

Comment: That's what goes *under* the shadow. *Drawing* the shadow over top does not depend on what's underneath it.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not an expert on this stuff by any means, an amateur really. Currently all the things rendered on the map are rendered as map markers. There is a way for me to render other things over top of the map view without them being map markers or part of the map?